# How to check for object of particular type in a HashSet in windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a `HashSet` of generic type `UserControl`, which can have various UserControl (login, settings). I want to check whether the set contains object of any particular type (say login). If so i want to get that element.

I know its quite easy to do with a loop, but is there any better way?

Comment: *"better"* in what way? Faster? Without looping?

Comment: yes, so that i wont require any explicit looping (something like calling contains), and be more readable.

Comment: Is "implicit looping" ok? For instance when LINQ method internally does looping for you. Also how do you discriminate between various types of UserControls, are they strictly different class type or by a value of certain property?

Comment: @EmperorOrionii no they are different type, basically extended from UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it without a loop, because you need to try all elements of your collection to check their types. In fact, it does not matter that you have a hash set: it would work the same with a list, or any other enumerable. However, LINQ lets you hide the loop, like this:

```
var item = hashSet.OfType<DesiredType>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @ay89 The default value for all reference types and nullable value types will be `null`. For `struct`s and primitives it will be the value created with no-argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As @dasblinkenlight says you can use `OfType<T>()` LINQ method to hide the loop. His answer also uses `FirstOrDefault()` method so "contains element?" questions is rephrased to "is not null". Another way is to use `Count() > 0` after `OfType<T>()`.

```
var items = hashSet.OfType<DesiredType>();
if (items.Count() > 0) {
    DesiredType item = items.First();
    ...
}
```

Third way is to put predicate in the `FirstOrDefault()` method.

```
var item = hashSet.FirstOrDefault(x => 
    x.getType() == typeof(DesiredType)
);

if (item != null) {
    ...
}
```

If your set doesn't change that often, you can use `GroupBy(func)` to reduce computation complexity to *O(1)*. Idea is to build dictionary once and query it instead.

```
var groups = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<UserControl>>();
foreach(var group in hashSet.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()))
    groups.Add(group.Key, group);

    .
    .
    .

if (groups.ContainsKey(typeof(DesiredType)) {
    DesiredType item = items.First();
    ...
}
```